# Is it possible to define a list in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

Since it is allowed to do `a=5 ; echo $a`, I was wondering whether or not it is possible to declare lists and other data structures (such as tuples, dictionaries) in the terminal?

And if so, are they mutable or they must be `unset` first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `array`; the simplest method of creating an array variable is to assign a value to one of its indices:

```
TEST[0]=zero
TEST[1]=one
TEST[2]=two
```

or, with:

```
TEST=(zero one two)
```

now, you access it as follows:

```
${TEST[index]}
```

ie

```
echo "First Index: ${TEST[0]}"
```

or you can access all the items in an array in one of the following ways:

```
${TEST[*]}
${TEST[@]}
```

For more help, read [this usefull guide](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/arrays.html)

Comment: @user253956 You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible. You can use lists and its mutable.

Try something like this:

```
arr=(1 2 3)  
echo ${list}
echo ${list[1]}
arr[1]=4
echo ${list}
echo ${list[1]}
echo ${list} | xargs -n 1
```

And, for a dictionary you will need to build a hash function.

For know how to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467959/1585576

Its easy to iterate over a list with `xargs` and you also can add unit tests to your script:
https://code.google.com/p/shunit2/